# How to filter breeze.webapi returned entities from the server

Tags: entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api2, breeze

I have a standard breeze web-server which exposes the Project

```
[HttpGet]
public IQueryable<Project> Projects()
{
    return _db.Context.Projects;
}
```

How can i prevent a `Project` with `NoLongerExist=true` from  begin included in queries returned to the JavaScript client from here affecting the functionality of the breezejs client?.. um i would also like to hide this property also, people wont like to see *that their projects are not actually deleted!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this on your breeze controller...

```
public IQueryable<Project> Projects()
    {
        return _db.Context.Projects.Where(o => o.NoLongerExist == true);
    }
```

prevent json serialization of the NoLongerExist  property using data annotations on your model by doing this, i'm assuming you are using EF6 with JSON.NET on your backend...

```
[Table("Project")]
public partial class Project
{
    public Project()
    {

    }

    public int id { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public bool NoLongerExist  { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks good sir. The answer is perfect for my question... but it have also rise this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38270062/4155741) can you please help me with that too?